# How to use ROS gscam to get grayscale image

Tags: opencv, gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 12.04, ROS hydro and gscam to read webcam.
I can get color image easily by make

```
GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
```

Then I run gscam, rostopic **/camera/image_raw** gives me images.

However, I want to get single channel grayscale image from webcam directly, because my subsequent algorithms can only handle grayscale image (in opencv, the mat entries are CV_8UC1).

I tried

```
GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1 ! videobalance saturation=0.0 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
```

It does make the output image looks as grayscale, but rostopic **/camera/image_raw** still have 3 channels instead of channel 1. (**/camera/image_raw/step** is three times of **/camera/image_raw/width**).

How can I get single channel image from gscam? (**/camera/image_raw/step** equals to **/camera/image_raw/width**)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106111/how-to-use-ros-gscam-to-get-grayscale-image/) by [PaulYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/9366/paulyang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible the driver doesn't support that.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0